# Cloning external harddrive encrypted by bitlocker using dd

Tags: bitlocker, hard-drive

Hi I want to know if I use dd to clone an external hard drive encrypted by bitlocker to another external drive, can the clone always be opened using the same password or there are exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

DD is a bit for bit copy, barring disk malfunctions.  The copy should be fine and open with the same key. I've been doing this for years with LUKs encrypted disks with no issues.

- Make sure **neither drive is mounted** when you copy it.
- Make sure your target drive is **at least** as big as your source drive.

Consider your intended usage. If it's just a backup, you may find it more convenient to DD to a **file** instead of to a raw disk.

Raw disk copies are just like the original and can be mounted and opened the same as the original. You need to be careful about booting and mounting two or more identical clone drives at once as they can cross boot with a partition from drive one and another partition from drive two. They will work like this but you may discover later that changes are not in the drive/partition you thought they were.